# Convert JPEG image to MPEG-2 Video

Tags: video, software-rec, conversion, jpeg, mpeg

I am working on a digital screen unit which has a 2-3 second delay with still images, but no delay for MPEG-2 video. I have used Photoshop CS5 to export the JPEG into MPEG-2 (MP4(ISMA)), but the quality is poor and very limited.

The image size is 1280x768.

Is there any software that can achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this one frame or many? Have you tried ffmpeg? http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/

Comment: one frame, i did download ffmpeg, but i totally lost with how to use it.

Comment: Did you try using the guide I linked? Also, why do you want to encode your jpeg image into a video?

Comment: Yes Nick i did look at the guide u linked, i dont really understand it very well. i suppose this thing dont realli have a user interface, you have to mannually use conmmand, i am not very good at that... but i look more into it + this is reason why i have to use MPEG >> (my image size is 1280 x 768) I am working on a very stupied digital screen unit, it does delay with still image (2-3 secs), however perfect for Mpeg-2 video, so it really sh*t me to tear at the moment, any help would be appreciated.